# Trying to drop all tables in flask, RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to flask been working on a project for a month. I have already separated all the code into file and blueprints and I want to delete all my tables by doing `db.drop_all()` in cmd. So i can start my database entries from scratch, but I get `RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context.`
Here are part of my codes

the whole **__init__.py:**

```
   from flask import Flask
   from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
   from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
   from flask_login import LoginManager
   from flask_mail import Mail
   from testapp.config import Config

   db=SQLAlchemy()
   bcrypt = Bcrypt()
   login_manager = LoginManager()
   login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
   login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
   mail = Mail()

    def create_app(config_class=Config):
       app = Flask(__name__)
       app.config.from_object(Config)

       db.init_app(app)
       bcrypt.init_app(app)
l      login_manager.init_app(app)
       mail.init_app(app)

       from testapp.users.routes import users
       from testapp.posts.routes import posts
       app.register_blueprint(users)
       app.register_blueprint(posts)
       return app
```

My **config.py:**

```
    import os

    class Config:
      SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
      SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
      MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
      MAIL_PORT = 587
      MAIL_USE_TLS = True
      MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USERNAME')
      MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
```

All my tables in **models.py:**

```py
    from datetime import datetime
    from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
    from flask import current_app
    from testapp import db, login_manager
    from flask_login import UserMixin

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
      return User.query.get(int(user_id))

    class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
      email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
      image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
      password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
      posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
      return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"

    class Post(db.Model, UserMixin):
      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
      date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
      content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
      user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
      return f"User('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

Comment: Seems you left out the most important part of this puzzle, what is db and what does db.drop_all() do?

Comment: db is my SQLAlchemy's function variable and db.drop_all() to delete all my pre-existing tables from models.py so I can start with db.create_all() to create my database from scratch.

Comment: So what is the actual code?

Comment: So the __init__.py here is my projects main __init__.py file if you get it. I am still learning python and coding in general so I might not be able to use the correct terms. The thing is when i run cmd on my projects folder and try to delete all the existing tables I get the runtime error

Comment: Correct, so it is the code in db.drop_all() that is causing the error, so we need to see that code. If want to learn more about the error message see: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/

Comment: Thank you .Truns out add the context function as in the article just did the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on that question, i was just dumbly running `db.drop_all()` function without in the command line inserting the app context all i had to do was import and add the `app_context()` function inside `db.drop_all()`.
And here i thought something in my code was wrong, So for the people with same question dont refer my code, but just this answer.

Thank you @Adrian Klaver for the help.